# Can't assign account to Contact

Tags: apex, controller

For a visualforce page, in my constructor i'm assigning a variable and retrieving an account from an associated opportunity - when I do a system.debug I get the details I want:

```
myObject__c myObject = [SELECT etc... ];
System.debug(myObject.opportunity__r.account);
```

Output:

```
Account:{Name=Traffic, BillingStreet=Example 34, BillingCity=Example, BillingCountry=Example, BillingPostalCode=D-80807, Website=www.google.com, Id=003N000000iTbKxXXX, CurrencyIsoCode=USD}
```

But, when I try to save a contact using a save function, and assign this account, the contact is saved, but it doesn't have any account saved to it.

```
Contact newContact = new Contact();
newContact.FirstName = contactFirstName;
            newContact.LastName = contactLastName;
            newContact.Title = contactJobTitle;
            newContact.Email = contactEmail;
            newContact.Phone = contactPhone;
            newContact.Account = myObject.opportunity__r.account;
            newContact.event__c = myObject.opportunity__r.expo__r.show__c;

            insert newContact;
```

Everything else is assigned but there is nothing for account, but when I debug the same variable, it displays the required information. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact's Account accepts an ID field (the correct field to use is `AccountId`), try the following query:

```
Contact newContact = new Contact();
newContact.FirstName = contactFirstName;
        newContact.LastName = contactLastName;
        newContact.Title = contactJobTitle;
        newContact.Email = contactEmail;
        newContact.Phone = contactPhone;
        newContact.AccountId = myObject.opportunity__r.account.Id;
        newContact.event__c = myObject.opportunity__r.expo__r.show__c;

        insert newContact;
```

You were trying to set the entire Account object to the Contact's Account field.

Comment: I now have error - illegal assignment from Id to Account --- edit - I wasn't using AccountId.

Comment: Use newContact.AccountId = myObject.opportunity__r.account.Id; instead of newContact.Account

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please set it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving wrong API name here. Correct API name is `AccountID`. So change this line

```
newContact.AccountId = myObject.opportunity__r.accountID;
```

Comment: The correct API name of the Contact's Account Id is AccountId.